# I'd like to add an Implementation-Version to manifest in my warfile in maven

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'd like to add an Implementation-Version line to manifest in my warfile.with implementation version as projectname_mmddyyy.version.How can configure this in maven?

Answer (score 1):

See [Maven Archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html) for reference. The configuration should go like this:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        ...
    </archive>
</configuration>
```